# Django view not executing

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I'm implementing an excel export function in one of my django apps, but when I click the link that is supposed to execute the view, nothing happens, and the server is not running the view at all.

This is the button that is supposed to run that view:

```
<li class="nav-item mt-sm-2 mt-lg-0">
    <a href="{% url 'catalog:export_all_csv' %}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" download="OrdenesProximas" tabindex="0" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" title="¡Archivo descargado!" data-content="El archivo ha sido descargado exitosamente.">
        <i class="uil-file"></i>
            Exportar catálogo a Excel
    </a>
</li>
```

My urls.py for the app:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'catalog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('catalog/list/', views.ProductList.as_view(), name='product_list_table'),
    path('catalog/add/', views.create_product, name='add_product'),
    path('catalog/category/add/', views.CategoryCreate.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('catalog/<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('catalog/<slug>/list/', views.CategoryProductList.as_view(), name='category_product_list_table'),
    path('catalog/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('catalog/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('catalog/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/edit/', views.edit, name='product_edit'),
    path('catalog/export_csv/', views.export_csv, name='export_all_csv'),
]
```

The view:

```
@login_required
def export_csv(request):
    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
    categories = Category.objects.filter(company=request.user.profile.company)
    queryset = Product.objects.filter(category__in=categories)
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = f'filename=productos.csv'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['Id de Producto', 'Categoría', 'Nombre del producto', 'SKU', 'Código de barras',
        'Marca', 'Proveedor', 'Color', 'Medidas', 'Descripción', 'Observaciones', 'Precio 1', 'Precio 2',
        'Precio 3', 'Impuesto (%)', 'Costo de fabricación'])
    for item in queryset:
        writer.writerow([item.id, item.category.name, item.name, item.sku, item.barcode, item.brand,
            item.provider, item.color, item.measures, item.description, item.observations, item.price_1,
            item.price_2, item.price_3, item.tax, item.fabrication_cost])
    return response
```

As far as I know, the url is correct so it should be entering the view, downloading the csv file in a new tab, but it just reloads the page and does nothing.

Comment: Could you give some info about project structure: the view, path and html your button is in?

Comment: Don't you forget `attachment`? `response['Content-Disposition'] = "attachment; filename='productos.csv'"`

Comment: @albar I corrected it to what you sent and now it is exporting the HTML of the page instead of a CSV file. I have another view that does the exact same thing in another app but it works just fine.

Comment: @Razenstein what do you mean? The rest of the project is working just fine. It is only this one view which is failing to run.

Comment: Can you please confirm that the view `path('catalog/<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),` is not being triggered instead of the export. I think this URL might be executed as its the first matching URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it might be the case that your url `product_list_by_category` is being picked up as the first matching URL. Django urls work such that the first matching URL is executed.

By changing the order of your urls your export should then work.

```
app_name = 'catalog'

urlpatterns = [
    path('catalog/list/', views.ProductList.as_view(), name='product_list_table'),
    path('catalog/add/', views.create_product, name='add_product'),
    path('catalog/category/add/', views.CategoryCreate.as_view(), name='add_category'),
    path('catalog/export_csv/', views.export_csv, name='export_all_csv'),  # note this is before the slug capture.
    path('catalog/<slug:category_slug>/', views.product_list, name='product_list_by_category'),
    path('catalog/<slug>/list/', views.CategoryProductList.as_view(), name='category_product_list_table'),
    path('catalog/', views.product_list, name='product_list'),
    path('catalog/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/', views.product_detail, name='product_detail'),
    path('catalog/<int:id>/<slug:slug>/edit/', views.edit, name='product_edit'),
    
]
```

The import thing to take away from this is that django will execute the first url which matches a pattern, even if the pattern later on in the list is a "closer match".

For debugging such issues the Django debug toolbar can be really useful. Under the request tab (once setup). You get given a table like below, which tells you which function was called with what args.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| View function    | Arguments |Keyword arguments                              |URL name    |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|myapp.views.MyView| ()        | {'pk': '55959533-9df0-427f-a904-79207f2613a3'}|product_list|
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```